# Lebesgue integrability of a composite function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $a, b\in R$ be such that $a<b$ 
and $u\in L([a, +\infty);R)$. Prove that 
$$
v(t)=\frac{b-a}{(b-t)^2}u\left(\frac{b-a}{b-t}+a-1\right)\in L([a, b];R).
$$
Thank you for all helping and guidance.

**My effort.** I intend to use the following theorem to solve the problem

**Theorem 1.** Suppose $g: [a, b)\rightarrow R$ is a function having finite derivatives almost everywhere on $[a, b]$ and $f : [a, \infty] \rightarrow R$ is a Lebesgue integrable function such that the range of g is contained in $[a, \infty]$. Then $f (g(x))$ g'(x) is Lebesgue integrable on [a, b].

Let $\displaystyle w(t)=\frac{b-a}{b-t}+a-1, t\in [a, b)$. Then $w: [a, b)\rightarrow R$ is a function having finite derivatives almost everywhere on $[a, b]$. Since
$$
v(t)=-w^\prime(t)u(w(t))
$$
and $u\in L([a,+\infty);R)$ then by **Theorem 1** we have $v\in L([a, b]; R)$.

Please help me to check this solution and where we can find a proof of the above **Theorem 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea (to make the change of variables) is correct. However, *Theorem 1* is unlikely to be found in the literature (even if it's true), because there is little interest in having $f(g(x))g'(x)$ integrable without knowing that $$\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)\,dt \tag{1}$$

And just having having finite derivatives almost everywhere" doesn't get you $(1)$. For example, let $g$ be the standard Cantor staircase and $f(x)\equiv 1$: then $(1)$ turns into $0=1$.

Your function $w$ is in fact a diffeomorphism. The change of variable formula for diffeomorphisms is, e.g., Theorem 2.47 in Folland's *Real Analysis* (and in most real analysis books).